# output of find to diff as argument

Tags: shell, unix

My problem,

During a build process a.c is copied into several directories and few of them get patched and few don't. I have a pre-patched file with me and I want to diff against all the files that are found in the directories. How do I solve this ?

Any help will be appreciated. My google search did not yield any success..

zerO One

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
find . -name a.c | xargs -I $$ diff ~/good/a.c $$
```

Option `-I` is used for replacing text

See man pages for more details: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: The double dollar is just a placeholder for one if the the a.c files provided by find?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of xargs, just use `-exec`.

```
find . -name a.c -exec diff ~/good/a.c {} \;
```

The `{}` means the file just found. The escaped semicolon ends the exec options.

If you want the output too just capture it like this:

```
find . -name a.c -exec diff ~/good/a.c {} \; 2>&1 | tee diff.out
```

The `2>&1` captures both stdout and stderr. `tee` lets you watch and save the results at the same time. You could just use `find 2>&1 > diff.out` if you want to automate this.

Hope this helps. If not, update to let us know what else you need.